# Tkinter: How do I Bold 'small part' of a text within a paragraph?

Tags: python, tkinter

**Tkinter: How do I Bold 'small part' of a text within a paragraph?**

**Desired Output:**

> **Date:** 12/07/2021

**Current Code:**

```
currentDate = (now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))

dateText = str("Date: " + currentDate)
canvas.create_text(15, 25, anchor='w', text=dateText, font=('Helvatical bold',12) , fill='white')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do, first write only `"Date :"` and after that write `Actual Date` using simple font.

```
currentDate = (now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))

datee = "Date: "
canvas.create_text(15, 25, anchor='w', text=datee, font=('Helvatical bold',12) , fill='white')
dateText = str(currentDate)
canvas.create_text(20, 25, anchor='w', text=dateText, font=('<Some simple font>',12) , fill='white')
```

If this solves your problem then don't forget to mark this as an accepted answer.

Comment: @Kshitz I guess I could do that; I was wondering if there was better way. Thank you.

Comment: @BartSimpson there are canvas tags, which I am surprised weren't included in this answer

Comment: I don't think there is a better way to do that, because you are trying to write in canvas.@Matiiss What do you mean by that? I didn't understand it?

Comment: @Kshitiz there is a way better option and that is using tags (to an extent better, still would need to have two create text entries, I think)

Comment: @Matiiss If we have to create two text entires then doesn't it meant same?

Comment: @Kshitiz at least with tags, formatting could be easier (maybe?), I had a thought of maybe adding Text widget to canvas (it would make it more complicated but if put into a class or sth, easily reusable)

Comment: @Matiiss What would you like to do edit answer and provide as alternatives or give another answer?

Comment: @Kshitiz probably gonna TRY writing my own answer

Comment: @Kshitiz nope, seems a bit too complicated (maybe it is not but right now I don't want to research anything too much) so Your solution is good enough (could place it in a function or sth to make it more reusable maybe) but still could maybe use tags for formatting or sth

Comment: Fine then! @BartSimpson mark this as an accepted answer!